# RegisterRestClient WebApplicationException empty response entity

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, quarkus

The problem is:

- I have my @RegisterRestClient jaxrs client in quarkus.
- Server replies 500. (Expected).
- I then catch WebApplicationException thrown from calling the jaxrs client.
- WebApplicationException has getResponse() method.
- The problem is WAE.getResponse().readEntity() is empty.

The solution to this problem is actually known and described here:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/17153#issuecomment-841573713
Also here: [Resteasy error response body is unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68828392/resteasy-error-response-body-is-unreachable/68828710#68828710)

The question is: why is that call to WAE.getResponse().readEntity() throws a no entity exception?
It just seems counterintuitive.

I tried to enable http.wire logging and it appears httpclient reads the full error response body anyway. So performance probably was not an issue here.

Comment: What version of Quarkus/RESTEasy are you using? You might be seeing the results of https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-2781

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Makes sense, thank you.